separate objects by vertex group
how can I separate objects by vertex group? I have this script but I want the script to only separate it by the first 10 vertex groups otherwhise it needs too much time.



scene = bpy.context.scene

for ob in scene.objects:
    
    def main():
        origin_name = bpy.context.active_object.name
        keys = bpy.context.object.vertex_groups.keys()
        real_keys = []
        for gr in keys:
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
            # Set the vertex group as active
            bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_set_active(group=gr)

            # Deselect all verts and select only current VG
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
            bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_select()
            # bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='INVERT')
            try:
                bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type="SELECTED")
                real_keys.append(gr)
            except:
                pass
        for i in range(1, len(real_keys) + 1):
            bpy.data.objects['{}.{:03d}'.format(origin_name, i)].name = '{}.{}'.format(
                origin_name, real_keys[i - 1])


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
        
#Switch back to object mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```


To loop through just the first 10 vertex groups:
# Loop through the first 10 groups
for gr in keys[:10]:

However, your code layout seems...confusing. Probably wrong. Why are you looping through objects and defining the main function inside the loop? I'm guessing that perhaps is meant to be laid out like:
scene = bpy.context.scene
def main():
    for ob in scene.objects:
        # ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

    #Switch back to object mode
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')


Thank you. Where do I need to place it in my code?

The new line for gr in keys[:10]: replaces the line for gr in keys:
